# Using Maven to build an Eclipse Plugin - latest opinions

Tags: java, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am building a plugin for Eclipse - but as we use Maven as a standard build platform I would like to be able to build the plugin using Maven.

I have found a previous question about using Maven with Eclipse Plugins - but as it is a year old I thought it was worthwhile collecting some new answers:

[Is it currently possible to build Eclipse Plugins by Maven AND have nice IDE Integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545531/is-it-currently-possible-to-build-eclipse-plugins-by-maven-and-have-nice-ide-inte)

It seems that Tycho has not been driven forward much in the last year - but has anything else been created that fulfils this need or is there an easier way?

Does anyone recommend still the Maven PDE plugin? Is this a cumbersome solution as it is just a wrapper for ANT scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the Tycho mailing list and I see plenty of feedback that suggests that people are successfully building plug-ins using Maven.  My current project isn't doing OSGi development, so I can't vouch from personal experience with the latest version of Tycho.  It's also worth pointing out that Tycho currently supports (to the best of my knowledge) a manifest-first approach to building plug-ins (as apposed to POM-first) - this might be a factor in deciding if Maven/Tycho fits your project.

Comment: Why is there no activity on the site? The documentation (e.g. 0.4.0 roadmap has not been updated since April last year.).

Also the 0.4.0 build is shown as having a blocking bug currently on the builds page.

Comment: The website doesn't give a good impression - true.  The current activity appears to all take place on the mailing list.  Here's a very recent write-up on using Tycho: http://mattiasholmqvist.se/

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that Tycho has not been driven forward much in the last year - but has anything else been created that fulfils this need or is there an easier way?

The project is definitely active (have a look at the [git repository](http://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-tycho)), regardless of the updates of its website and AFAIK Sonatype is using it (successfully) for [m2eclipse](http://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-tycho).