# RCP build with maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp

How to build and package RCP (Rich client Platform) using Eclipse.

Is it possible to build as a `.jar` file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545531/is-it-currently-possible-to-build-eclipse-plugins-by-maven-and-have-nice-ide-inte is dated, but maybe related/relevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [Maven Tycho](http://tycho.sonatype.org/). I find it a lot easier to use than the PDE ant scripts.

The [itp04 RCP example](https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-tycho/tree/master/tycho-demo/itp04-rcp) is a good project to get started.

Comment: It still seems like a lot of pain to get working, hopefully it will be streamlined a bit more soon. +1 for the link.

Comment: how to download this... app. ?

Comment: You do not need to download Tycho itself. It will be automatically downloaded by Maven(3).

Comment: Both links are now broken. Correct link is http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/about/

Answer (score 2):

We use Maven 3 and the sonatype-tycho plugin to build our Eclipse RCP-based application. It allows a **plugin-first approach**, i.e. you define the dependencies only in the `plugin.xml` using the editor of Eclipse. You don't have to care about dependencies in the `pom.xml` as these are managed by tycho.

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed instructions at [Apache Felix maven Bundle](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) page on how to do this.
Alternatively, There are some quickstart [maven archetypes](https://github.com/kiggundu/archetypes) you could download based on these instructions and experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped PDE/Build by Maven manually. You can find an example in my answer to my own question:
[How to set up Eclipse PDE/Build with Indigo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484729/how-to-set-up-eclipse-pde-build-with-indigo)